# How to find indices of nth occurance of a substring and subset the strings according to these indices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a columns that contains strings and i want to slice it from second space to 4th space. In general, in a column of strings, How do i 1. find the indices of nth occurance of a substring 2. subset the strings according to these indices

I am looking for a solution without involving regexes

Comment: Emmmm some data and your expected out put ..

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df['column'].str.split().str[2:4].str.join(' ')
```